# Can a creature wearing boots of landing be tripped?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, combat, psionics

The [***boots of landing***](http://dndsrd.net/psionicItemsU.html#boots-of-landing) (*Expanded Psionics Handbook* 172) (1,000 gp; 1 lb.) say

> While wearing boots of landing, you land on your feet no matter how far you fall, and you take 2 fewer dice of damage from the fall than normal (thus, a fall of 20 feet or less deals you no damage).

Is a creature wearing the *boots* still vulnerable to being [tripped](http://dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#trip)?

Comment: Argh! "These boots allow the wearer to recover instantly from a fall and can absorb some damage from falling *once per day*." A *thousand* gp for *that*? Seriously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes

Oddly enough, a trip attack is a special attack which inflicts the "prone" status. It does not count as falling. It is in fact possible to trip without your feet leaving the ground during your entire trip. (pun intended.)

This is a case where combat has been generalized and does not match real world physics.

Furthermore as specified in the [Environment section: Falling from the SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/environment.htm#falling) , a character is only considered "falling" if said character traverses 10' or more vertically (ie: towards gravity, and typically in an uncontrolled fashion).

Comment: Something something *tripping flying creatures* something something.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Nobody said you couldn't be prone in midair. ^^ Beside, a trip attack in mid-air would have to target the wings...

Comment: That section on falling says nothing like _"considered "falling" if said character traverses 10' or more"_. What it does say is that you have to fall 10' or more to be at risk of taking damage. The first sentence of the following section, Falling Objects states "when they fall more than 10 feet", implying you can fall less than 10 feet.

Comment: The basic rule is simple: **1d6 points of damage per 10 feet fallen...** Less than 10' = no damage... No damage = not falling. See also the Falling objects section just below, where it mentions "provided it falls *at least 10'*. Welcome to D&D Physics 101. ^-^

Comment: @Wyrmwood Although, to be honest, the bit about falling less than 10' is actually moot, (though I take your point) as the trip attack does not depend upon a falling effect or status in order to work, instead it is a special attack that inflicts a special status.

Comment: I emphatically concede that you can trip someone with boots of landing. The re-definition of falling doesn't add to the answer.  I believe this answer would be best if it ended after the word "status" and the humor and commentary were left out.

Comment: The commentary on falling is partly in response to tripping flying creatures and partly towards your comments. D&D rules define falling as taking damage after moving 10' and hitting the ground. The falling condition only exists after you've moved 10' or more. It says literally nothing about less than 10'. It is left undefined. Thus my character could step off a 9' roof, hit the ground (taking no damage) and not be considered falling at any point in time, per the rules.  This addresses the in-between cases of someone being swept off their feet and thus "falling". Humor is the spice of life.

Comment: I beg to differ. D&D makes no such claim about the definition of falling and the previous quote (_when they fall more than 10 feet_) demonstrates that. I can see how one comes to that conclusion, but it's an interpolated result from a limited context, not a definition.

Comment: Your quote actually proves my position.

Comment: How? The rules say precisely the opposite of your belief. _Fall more than 10 feet_ can only make sense if one is able to fall less than 10 feet. Otherwise you would not need the "more than 10 feet" part. I get it, it sounds cool to find nonsense in the rules, but you won't find this one in the text.

Comment: Nice manipulation of my position: "the rules say", "my belief"? Into fallacies much? What the rules "say" is fall more than 10 feet = damage. Note that the SRD title is "falling", and the subtitle is "falling damage". This grammatical usage automatically implicitly makes falling equate to falling damage, or in other words, it's only falling if you take damage from the sudden stop. And the logical correlation is that if you don't take damage as defined, you weren't falling, no matter how much distance you moved. Let's move this to chat if you feel like continuing.

Answer (score 3):

A character wearing *boots of landing* is still vulnerable to being tripped.

The boots only protect you from falling and prevent you from going prone when you fall.  They do not make you immune to the *prone* condition.